# Understanding Cones in general and the Ice cream Cone

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis, visualization, convex-cone

### Definitions

- Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the n dimensional Eucledean space.
- With $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, let $S^G$ be the set of all finite nonnegative linear combinations of elements of $S$.
- A set $K$ is defined to be a cone if $K = K^G$.
- A set is convex if it contains with any two of its points, the line segment between the points.

### Questions

1. From the above definitions, does it not follow that every cone is convex?
   If not what will be an example of a nonconvex cone?
2. $K_n = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sqrt{(x^2_2 + \cdots + x^2_n) } \le x_1 \right\}$ is called ***the ice cream cone***. I can see how it is convex and the fact that it is a cone. But I do not understand the ice cream part.

Why is called the ice cream cone? how can i visuslise it or at least get some intuition on what it means.

It seems to be a set made up of infinite number of verctor dimensions i.e. $\{ n \in \mathbb{Z} : n \ge 2 \}$ and infinite vectors in each dimension. But I can't see the shape.

More generally, is the concept of a cone here in any way related to the geometric shape?

Comment: I think that the "ice cream" cone really is only the wafer. There's no ball of ice cream there, only an infinite wafer starting at the origin and having the positive $x_1$ axis as axis of rotational symmetry.

Comment: It is called an ice-cream cone because in 3D it looks as shown here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#cones (at least its boundary).

Answer (score 1):

"Ice cream" is not a commonly used technical term in this context, so don't take it too seriously. It looks like it's just one author's attempt at a cutesey and memorable name.

A more dignified term for this shape in the $n=3$ case would be (the interior of one sheet of) a **right-angled circular cone**.

Whether it has anything to do with ice cream is a cultural matter. Where I come from, ice cream is often served in cones rolled from sweet flatbread with a top angle somewhere between 20° and 45°; they don't really match your shape. But I think that at least some places in the English-speaking world cones for ice cream are indeed right-angled (and made from cast sugar without flour).

Answer (score 0):

Of course a cone is convex. Let $x^1,x^2 \in S^G$. Then $x^i = \sum_{s \in S}\xi^i_s s$, where all $\xi^i_s \ge 0$ and only finitely many $\xi^i_s \ne 0$. For each $t \in [0,1]$ we have $\eta_s = t \xi^1_s + (1 - t) \xi^2_s \ge 0$ and $\eta_s \ne$ only for finitely many $s$. Hence $t x^1 + (1-t)x^2 = \sum_{s \in S}\eta_s s \in S^G$.

The name "ice-cream cone" has been explained in Michal Adamaszek's comment.